# detect if socket.io emit did not work

Tags: node.js, socket.io

How can i detect if a message did not reach my node.js+socket.io server. I have an emit from the server for message sent success.

```
socket.on('message', function(msg) {
var sendersusername = msg.source;
if (io.sockets.sockets[socket.id] != undefined)
{
  io.sockets.sockets[socket.id].emit('messagesentsuccess',
               {"user": msg.target,
               "message":msg.message
                 });
}
});
```

from this code i get a success message when a message reaches the server. How do i know if the message could not be sent to the server?

Comment: you'll probably get some sort of error in the console if it doesn't work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use

```
socket.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

to detect errors`

Comment: does this work on the client side or the server side?

Comment: if u want to detect the server side connection with the client side you can use

var socket = io.connect();

socket.on('connect', function () {
  alert('Socket is connected.');
});

socket.on('disconnect', function () {
  alert('Socket is disconnected.');
});

Comment: how can I tell which particular socket emit failed ?

Comment: here is the answer to tell which particular emit failed : http://stackoverflow.com/a/11382931/1290746